# HOW TO Make Python Script run from startup in background on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c4Et.png)I have attached a shortcut of my Python file in startup using `shell:startup` so that after user login python script is popping up but i don't want it to pop-up is there any way to sort this to not pop-up.
ideas please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want py file to pop up immediately after login

you can try
add this in the starting of your python file

```
import win32gui, win32con
import time
the_program_to_hide = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(the_program_to_hide , win32con.SW_HIDE)

time.sleep(10)

win32gui.ShowWindow(the_program_to_hide , win32con.SW_SHOW)
```

this will hide the window for 10 seconds after startup and show it

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can start your python script in the a minimized window with the help of executing python script from command line.

Example:

```
cmd /c start /B /min mspaint
```

Comment: This is one of the worst method existing to start Microsoft Paint and this answer has nothing to do with the question on which was asked how to run a Python script in background on Window start without showing any window. Starting Windows command processor resulting in opening a console window to start Microsoft Paint with a minimized application window is of no use for running a Python script in background on startup of Windows.